# Google SEO: Preview not available

Tags: seo

The pagerank of My website is 3.  But when I search sgyuan in Google, I didn't any summary of my website, and the Preview is not avaible also.

And google translate is not working also.

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not using the meta nosnippet tag that prevents Google from displaying snippets and previews in search results.

Make you do not have this in your Html

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="nosnippet">
```

More info here.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1062498

Anyway, for some site could take some days for Google to create your preview, consider wait and use Google Web Master Tools.

Please also read this article in case you use AJAX for your site

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html